# Android Gradle Plugin warnings when building the release APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm getting the following Android Gradle Plugin warnings when I try to build the release APK from Android Studio:

```
library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser  
library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer    
library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser  
library class android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser  
library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser  
library class android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser   
library class android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser  
library class android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.graphics.drawable.ScaleDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
library class android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer    
library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser    
library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser 
there were 32 instances of library classes depending on program classes.    
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**Here is the build error:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:207)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:485)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:176)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm unable to create the release APK as a result of these errors. But I'm able to test my app and also create the debug APK successfully. I then tried to create the release APK of the OLD version of my code which worked without any issues back then, but I'm still getting the same errors.

**Here's my build.gradle (app) file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cg.lrceditor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
}
```

Not sure why, but if I set both `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to false, I am able to create the release APK successfully. But then the app size won't be optimized.

I've tried ignoring the warnings using `-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**` or `-ignorewarnings` in `proguard-rules.pro` and I'm able to generate the release APK, but then when I launch the app, it crashes. Here's the relevant stack trace of the crash:

```
2019-03-26 10:46:28.413 19982-19982/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cg.lrceditor, PID: 19982
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method asAttributeSet(Lorg/a/a/a;)Landroid/util/AttributeSet; in class Landroid/util/Xml; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Xml' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
        at android.support.v7.view.g.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:125)
        at com.cg.lrceditor.HomePage.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomePage.java:294)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3315)
        at android.support.v4.app.h.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:364)
        at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.f$a.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332)
        at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.m$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:1454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

`HomePage.java:294` is `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);`.

---

How do I fix these issues with `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` on?

Comment: add this line -ignorewarnings in proguard-rules.pro nad check.

Comment: @Varma I can get the APK if I do that, but my app wouldn't launch. See my edited post

Comment: can you post build error when you toggle view on left side ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy Found that view. I ran with `--stacktrace` and here is the output: https://pastebin.com/rVqiGa5D

Comment: are you using any module dependencies ?

Comment: @Spikatrix please post every piece of relevant info in the question body, using pastebin is not recommended since the info will expire after some time and stackoverflow is meant to be a longterm informational resource

Comment: @ManoharReddy I have `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' }` in `build.gradle (Project)`

Comment: @kkarakkI didn't post it here as that output is almost 500 lines long. The paste expiry is set to never.

Comment: try adding this rule in proguard  `-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }`

Comment: @ManoharReddy Thanks. Yes, that works. I'm not sure if ignoring warnings is a good idea though. Anyway, Please post an answer

Comment: you are not ignoring warning , above rule states that "do not apply proguard to classes under package `org.xmlpull.v1`"

Comment: @ManoharReddy I meant that I have to use both `-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**` and `-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }` for it to work. If I don't use the `-dontwarn`, I still get the same errors.

Comment: Ok , maximum it should not cause any error , if you are getting any error try adding those packages too to the proguard rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
>
> library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
>
> library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer

As mention in the first error there is some problem with package `org.xmlpull.v1`
so just ignore them from the proguard . Add this rule to your proguard

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }
```

Comment: Ever since I did this, I'm getting some `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` crash reports from some users on app startup. Those reports indicate all the users using Android 5.1. The line it crashes on is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);` which is in the `onCreate` method of my activity. Any idea what might be causing them? The full code is available [here](https://github.com/Spikatrix/LRC-Editor) if you need to look at it

Comment: @Spikatrix  It should not be related to this proguard rule , can you add full exception ?

Comment: I'm seeing that crash ever since I did this which is why I'm suspecting something related to this is causing the issue. [Here](https://pastebin.com/rFLRU2pV) is the full stack trace

Comment: @Spikatrix sorry I cannot say what the issue is , I cloned the project checked every line in `activity_home_page` every thing seems ok to me . I don't have a 5.1 device so I cannot reproduce the issue . Here are few thing you can try 1) Try changing the images which are used in the layout 2)try removing references to dimens, attrs and give values directly .

Comment: No problem. I appreciate you going far and beyond to try to help me. Thank you for that. By the way, I ran my application on a virtual Android 5.1 emulator and it worked without any issues. Also, not all Android 5.1 users have that crash. I got the reports from a very few users.

Answer (score 0):

You are not aware of the Proguard rules. Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) link to understand proguard rules.

What ever you are using all class files will be shrinked by default. If you are using any libraries,it is your responsibility to keep those classes by mentioning it in the proguard rules file.

Try this line in proguard file

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```